# Add habitat tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recommend we add a tag `habitat`, and reassign questions currently tagged `helix` that are primarily about Habitat set up, errors and troubleshooting to this tag. This would refocus `helix` on Helix design principles and the contents of the [Helix](http://helix.sitecore.net) guide.  (Motivation: I wanted to view current discussion of Helix guide, and had to wade through many Habitat questions.)

- Sample Helix question: [Helix and field sources](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/helix-and-field-sources)
- Sample Habitat question: [Controller Rendering Issues in Habitat](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/controller-rendering-issues-in-habitat)

Answer (score 6):

Yah. This was rooted in a judgment call we made a while back, where we foresaw that Habitat discussion would die out - given it's only a demo site. For some reason it hasn't :P

I have removed the forced synonym for `habitat` now, that was forcing this to `helix`.

You, and anyone, is free to retag these questions to their heart's desire now ;-)

Comment: Okay, late night project. :)